# Trends of linear thermal expansion coefficient across a period

Tags: thermodynamics

Are there any trends in linear thermal expansion coefficient in transition elements?
By thermal expansion theorem, I mean.
$$\alpha = \dfrac{1}{L}\dfrac{\Delta L}{\Delta T}$$
What are the contributing factors that change $\alpha$, such as charge or atomic mass number?

Comment: A related search gives for the first hit Söderlind & Johansson's "[Calculated thermal expansion of d and f transition metals](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Per-Soederlind/publication/223169400_Calculated_thermal_expansion_of_d_and_f_transition_metals/links/59ee3888a6fdcc32187db148/Calculated-thermal-expansion-of-d-and-f-transition-metals.pdf)."

Comment: Thank you very much! That article answered my question!